# Загрузка файла в форме

Tags: html, form

Почему при отправке формы на почту отправляется только названия файла, а сам файл нет?

```
<form action="mailto:rproger@mail.ru" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="file" name="foto" size=50 value="ваш аватар">
<input type="submit"><input type="reset">
```

Comment: Потому что "Гладиуолус"! =)

А по существу: где код (формы и обработчика)?

Comment: Залейте на pastebin.com код формы, и код скрипта, который ее обрабатывает. Уровень наших экстрасенсорных способностей сегодня не велик, из-за растущей фазы луны и гильгокамеского солнцестояния. Поэтому очень трудно понять проблему без кода. Извините.

Comment: @Рома Прогер, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @ХэшКод Этот текст уже в качестве баннера нужно ставить с указанием на иконку форматирования)))

А лучше флеш баннер, как видео ролик чтобы прям)

Comment: Не вижу закрывающего тега формы : </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно, передаются файлы через такую форму `<form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="userfile" /></form>`

А на php нужно принимать с помощью `$_FILES['userfile'];` и проверять.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `enctype="multipart/form-data"` надо, а не `enctype="text/plain"`.